# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to make a program that finds whether a number is prime or not.

File 2:

```
class Number():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = float(x)
    def is_prime(x):
        x = x
        Div = 2
        while ((x / 2) > Div):
            if(x == 2):
                return True
            elif(x == 3):
                return True
            else:
                while((x / 2) > Div):
                    if(x%Div == 0):
                        return False
                    elif(Div >= (x / 2)):
                        return True
                    else:
                        Div = Div + 1
```

File 1:

```
from File2 import *

N = Number(10)

print N.is_prime()
```

When I run it I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "File 1", line 5, in <module>
print N.is_prime()
File "File 2", line 19, in is_prime
while ((x / 2) > Div):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'int'
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm curious why you've made a wrapper class for a number.  Just use Python's numbers directly and write a stand alone function `is_prime`.  Going with an object oriented approach is overkill here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Daniel Roseman has addressed the syntax problems with your class definition. Here's a correction to your chosen algorithm itself, which as it stands returns `None` (which is what a function returns if it exits without encountering an explicit `return` statement) if `x` is prime, and identifies 4 as a prime number. Your nested `while` loops are not necessary. Try:

```
class Number():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = float(x)
    def is_prime(self):
        x = self.x
        if(x == 2):
            return True
        elif(x == 3):
            return True
        else:
            Div = 2
            while((x / 2) >= Div):
                if(x%Div == 0):
                    return False
                else:
                    Div = Div + 1
        return True

for i in range(2,36):
    N = Number(i)
    print i, N.is_prime()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is very confused. The first parameter to an instance method in any Python class is always the instance itself, usually called `self`. Just because you've called the argument `x` doesn't make it the actual attribute `x` that you set originally: you would have to refer to `x.x`. But better to use the standard names, and reference `self.x`:

```
def is_prime(self):
    x = self.x
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually trying to do `self / 2`. Parameter `x` points to *self* and since it is the instance of a `Number` class, you are getting this error.

You need to replace `x` passed to your method with `self.x` and change the method's signature to that:

```
def is_prime(self):
    x = x # remove this
    Div = 2
    while ((self.x / 2) > Div):
        ....
```